# Retrieving values from SQLite3 resultset seems inconsistent?

Tags: ruby, sqlite

If I run `execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1")[0][0]`, I'll get back the first field from the first row of that resultset.

If I run `prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?").execute(1)[0][0]`, which to me seems like it should return an identical result, I get the error `[] NoMethodError`.

I can't for the life of me figure out why and the documentation seems really sparse. What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two `execute` methods are not identical and are returning different things.

In the first instance, you are calling [`execute`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby/SQLite3/Database:execute) on `Database`, which returns a simple array. Then you correctly index into it with `[]`.

However, `prepare` returns a `Statement` object which you then call [`execute`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby/SQLite3/Statement:execute) on. This instead returns a `ResultSet`, which doesn't have the same semantics as an array.

You might be looking for [`execute!`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby/SQLite3/Statement:execute!).